# Spring Scheduled Timer is executed twice

Tags: java, spring, timer, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have seen there are some similar questions; but most of them have duplicated bean that causes this issue. Despite that there is no configuration duplication in my application context definition, my scheduled timer is also executed twice.

Here is my definition in `applicationContext.xml`. Just enabled annotation driven tasks.

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

And here is my timer service:

```
@Component
public class SessionTimer {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30000)
    public void killSession() {
      // business processes
      logger.debug("Current time: " + RIAUtil.sdfTimestampWithSeconds.format(now));
    }

}
```

Any ideas behind this issue?

Comment: any chance you have `<context:component-scan>` as well ?

Comment: either u are loading the applicationContext.xml twice or you have <context:component-scan> at two places. Enable debug logging in log4j or logback or what ever you sue and read the logs output for spring happenings from top to bottom till the container is initialized.

Comment: @JavaBond yes I have; otherwise my other components such as controllers, services and repositories are not autowired.